# Expand open_basedir for virtualhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, php

All my virtualhosts have their own directive open_basedir, like:

php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/user/data:."

How can I add a path to open_basedir globaly to all virtualhosts?

Comment: You would need to add inside each virtualhost `php_admin_value open_basedir /my/main/path/:/my/second/path/` but like said bellow it is a very bad pratice unless you are making multiple paths to a user where the paths are OWNED by that user and not sharing those with any other virtualhost that are not OWNED by that given user.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't. You have to add the global path in each vhost open_basedir

Answer (score 0):

I researched this a while back and the short answer is that radius is right, you can't.  Basing your server's security on open_basedir is generally not recommended as it is not foolproof.  Instead, you should look at using something like suexec + fastcgi or suPHP to keep your PHP applications secure.